# copying files to new folder with check for duplicates then change name

Tags: terminal, copy

I'm trying to recursively copy images from one directory structure to a single folder. But some files have the same name but they are different files, created at different times

I started with this terminal script.

```
    find /Volumes/allPreviews/2011 -iname '*.jpg' -exec cp {} /Volumes/iPhotoPreviews/2011 \;
```

It worked great until it overwrote some files in the new dir with duplicate names.

Now I need something that will check if the file I'm copying is named the same as any new files copied over and then add a suffix like "camera2".jpg

Comment: Why is this tagged with python? Have you tried any python code?

Comment: yeah i've tried writing it in python too. some trouble finding the right way to check the directory for the duplicate file though.